# background threading in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am a research student who just started the android programming for 3 weeks and I am trying to write an App which extracts data from accelerometer from the phone and writing it on my phone. My problem is that I would like to run my App (taking data from accelerometer) all time when the phone is up and running. What I mean is that my App has to run all time when somebody is calling, facebooking and so on. Is that possible? I would like to get some references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I mean is that my App has to run all time when somebody is
>   calling, facebooking and so on. Is that possible?

So for long-tasks you can use `AsyncTask` or `Services`. If you want to execute some task and it have to run also when its not connected with any `Activity`(for example Music player, RSS which still run also after release from memory by memory manager), you should decide to use `Services` and also you can combine `Services` with `AsyncTask`.

`Services` are strong tool but work with them is not trivial. You are able to execute only one `Service` in time and only one `Service` can running, one instance, one copy. This all is not free so you have to be careful because when you implement `Service` too dirty, it may cause premature exhaustion of battery.
There is more approaches how to start `Services` but you have to read some tutorial and guides.
I recommend to check this: [Services](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), [ServicesDemo - Using Android Services](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/60.html), [Android Service Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html), [Local Service | Android Tutorial for Beginners](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/09/android-developer-tutorial-for_04.html)

Also have look at [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), [Android Threads, Handlers and AsyncTask - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Services`. Look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. I was looking into mutlithreading for like a week and did not work out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your activity of your app to be closed, but still a process should be running at background doing your desired work, then you can use `Service, or IntentService` (Use intent service, in place like, you want an update after certain period of time).